# Stopping windows from creating multiple notification icons for a single application

Tags: .net, windows, winforms

This is a simple issue, but I just can't seem to find the proper description for it that can be easily searched, so I apologize if it's been addressed already.

I have a windows application that is dynamically updated after installation. The update process downloads a new set of files in zip format, unzips them in the app folder, then runs the new application. Its simple and does not use the windows installer system.

It seems however that windows 10 (and possibly windows 8) creates a notification icon for each version of the executable tho... which is making things messy for my clients.

Any idea how to force windows to use a single notification icon instead of creating a new one for each executable thats ever been used on a computer?

Any help appreciated!

Thanks,

Dave (App written in .NET, standard winforms app).

[image]

Comment: This can only go wrong if for some reason you let the program continue executing, even though it got updated.  That's not correct of course.  Or you make it stop with a sledge-hammer like Process.Kill().  That prevents the NotifyIcon from getting properly disposed and you get a "ghost" icon that is no longer connected to the process that owns it.  That's not correct of course, don't use a sledge-hammer.

Comment: Hi Hans. I am not talking about the notify icons in the task bar. I am talking about the modifiable notification "settings" in windows 10. I will attach a screenshot with the software name redacted in just a moment.

Comment: NOTE ON IMAGE: Sorry about the redaction.. .The company I am developing for is a bit of a mudge when it comes to that. In any case, thats what im talking about... Very annoying! I assume it uses the GUID of the executable or something to classify a unique "app" ... there must be some way to set this instead.

Comment: Is the path of the executable always the same or is it different for each updated version? Windows identifies the applications via the path.

Comment: It is always the same. The executable is also the same, but it has changed obviously, and its file version number has been incremented.